# "echo "password" | sudo -S <command>" asks for password

Tags: linux, passwords, sudo

I trying run a script without become the su user and I use this command for this:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S <command>
```

If I use this command for "scp", "mv", "whoami" commands, the command works very well but when I use for "chmod", the command asks for password for my user. I don't enter password and **the command works**. My problem is the system asks password to me. I don't want the system asks for password.

Problem ss is like this:

```
[myLocalUser@myServer test-dir]$ ls -lt
total 24
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root 1397 May 26 12:12 file1
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root  867 May 26 12:12 script1
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root 8293 May 26 12:12 file2
--wx-wx-wx 1 root root 2521 May 26 12:12 file3

[myLocalUser@myServer test-dir]$ echo "myPassw0rd" | sudo -S chmod 111 /tmp/test-dir/*
[sudo] password for myLocalUser: I DONT WANT ASK FOR PASSWORD

[myLocalUser@myServer test-dir]$ ls -lt
total 24
---x--x--x 1 root root 1397 May 26 12:12 file1
---x--x--x 1 root root  867 May 26 12:12 script1
---x--x--x 1 root root 8293 May 26 12:12 file2
---x--x--x 1 root root 2521 May 26 12:12 file3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` prints this prompt on `stderr` prior to reading the piped password.  Redirect standard error to avoid seeing it:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S command 2> /dev/null
```